# I unable to connect TYPO3 backend to front app

Tags: vue.js, typo3, headless, typo3-extensions

I have plain TYPO3 version 11.5.x setup with headless version 3.1.2. Backend working perfect and frontend URL returning proper JSON data.

API URL looks like: https://t3-pwa.ddev.site:4403/typo3/

I created `front` directory in the project root. Project directory looks like this.

##### **Directory**

- fileadmin
- front - created front app with `nuxt-typo3` contain node package

  - node_modules
  - server
  - jsconfig.json
  - nuxt.config.js
  - package.json
  - tsconfig.json
- typo3
- typo3conf
- vendor
- typo3temp
- .ddev
- index.php
- .htaccess

##### **Command**

- Created app with `yarn create nuxt-typo3`
- Configured with default settings
- Run `yarn dev`

It starts application properly but when I visit frontend on default url: http://localhost:3000 It does not starting.

Console Start app : https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDr6U.png

Front: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ms6l2.png

Console: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZoBm.png

**nuxt.config.js: Looks like this**

```
export default {
  /*
  ** Headers of the page
  */
  head: {
    title: process.env.npm_package_name || '',
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: process.env.npm_package_description || '' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
    ]
  },
  /*
  ** Customize the progress-bar color
  */
  loading: { color: '#ff8700' },
  /*
  ** Global CSS
  */
  css: [
  ],
  /*
  ** Plugins to load before mounting the App
  */
  plugins: [
  ],
  /*
  ** Nuxt.js dev-modules
  */
  buildModules: [
    // Doc: https://github.com/macopedia/nuxt-typo3-theme
    'nuxt-typo3-tailwind',
    // Doc: https://github.com/TYPO3-Initiatives/nuxt-typo3
    'nuxt-typo3',
  ],
  /*
  ** Nuxt.js modules
  */
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/pwa',
  ],
  /*
  ** TYPO3 module configuration
  ** https://github.com/TYPO3-Initiatives/nuxt-typo3
  */
  typo3: {
    baseURL: process.env.NUXT_HOST,
    forms: true,
    api: {
      baseURL: 'https://t3-pwa.ddev.site'
    },
  },
  typo3tailwind: {
    layouts: false
  },
  /*
  ** Build configuration
  */
  build: {
    /*
    ** You can extend webpack config here
    */
    extend (config, ctx) {
    }
  }
}
```

Also, default frontend URL returns the same JSON URL. Can anyone share some hint? Also, minimal solution from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your baseURL in frontend application is not valid. You should keep only `https://t3-pwa.ddev.site:4403` in `baseURL` in `nuxt.config.js` file.

Please remember that nuxt-typo3 frontend application tries to fetch `?type=834` URL at start, and if you add `/typo3` at start, it's not valid anymore.

You should adjust your baseURL, rebuild and you are ready to go. You can also take a look at our pwa-demo, which uses nuxt-typo3 and TYPO3 Headless with ddev https://github.com/TYPO3-Headless/pwa-demo.

Comment: I updated full config file. But, output is still same.